# Open plugin documentation in vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Vim plugins frequently provide text-based documentation in a `/doc` folder.

For example, [vim-orgmode](https://github.com/jceb/vim-orgmode/blob/master/doc/orgguide.txt), and [vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/blob/master/doc/vim-go.txt).

How can one easily open the documentation from within vim?

Answer (score 4):

Each `doc` folder should have `:helptags` run. This will normally be done automatically by plugin managers. After that, any tag in the doc files should be a legal target for the `:help` command (for help files, "tag" being "the stuff between two asterisks"). Thus, since there's `*org*` in the vim-orgmode's doc file, you should be able to do `:help org` to jump there. You can also say `:help orgguide.txt` to open the file itself by name.

Answer (score 0):

Super simple: `:h <doc-name>`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Vim documentation](https://www.vim.org/docs.php):

> Vim's online documentation system, accessible via the :help command, is an extensive cross-referenced and hyperlinked reference. It's kept up-to-date with the software and can answer almost any question about Vim's functionality.